# Maximize breaks windows on GNOME 3.10.4

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I am having issues with GNOME 3.10.4. I used an extension (named `maximus two`) from [GNOME Shell Extensions](http://extensions.gnome.org) but upon installing, it broke maximization. I removed it and restarted the GNOME Shell, to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else experiencing this issue, you don't just need to restart the GNOME Shell, **you need to log out and back in as well**. This should fix the problem.